# asp.net dropdownlist display stored value as selected in dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form that contains multiple dropdowns, textboxes and images. I can insert dropdown seleted item in database, but when I am updating form I want that selected stored value to show at the top of the dropdown list. In short as selected.

Comment: Would be better if we see your work and what have you tried..

Comment: this.dropdown1.SelectedValue = "your value" ;

Comment: can you update question with relevant code

Comment: more than 30 item in my dropdown list.

Comment: @ insert - cmd= new sqlcomment("nsert into table values ('"+dropdownlist1.selectedvalue.tostring()+"')",con);

Comment: How about the method called Google Search... Please try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding your dropdown in pageload,then..

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //Bind Dropdown
        }
    }
```

Then you can set selected value as..

```
dropdown1.SelectedValue = "value" ;
```

Comment: Thanks for d comment. But I have more than 30 item in dropdownlist

Comment: I retrieve my dropdownlist value from database to label and display on page lode . but when select button edit, same lable value show in same dropdownlist as selected or on d top..that what I can update value

Comment: Can you put your code in the question,Where you are filling your dropdown etc?It will be helpfull..

Comment: Thank Jameem it works. but I insert dropdownlist as index and also retrive in int value. then append to dropdawnlist1.selectedindex.tostring= int value